# String splitting and operations on only some results

Tags: postgresql

I have strings that look like this:

```
schedulestart |             event_labels

2018-04-04    |   9=TTR&11=DNV&14=SWW&26=DNV&2=QQQ&43=FTW
```

When I look at it in the database.   I have code that relies in this string in this format to display a schedule with events with those labels on those days.

Now I find myself needing to break down the string in postgres for reporting/analysis, and I can't really pull out the string and parse it in another language, so I have to stick to postgres.

I've figured out a way to unpack the string so my results look like this:

```
User  ID | Schedule Start | Unpacked String
 2       | 2018-04-04     | TTR
 2       | 2018-04-04     | 9
 2       | 2018-04-04     | DNV
 2       | 2018-04-04     | 11
 2       | 2018-04-04     | SWW
 2       | 2018-04-04     | 14
 2       | 2018-04-04     | DNV
 2       | 2018-04-04     | 26

select schedulestart, unnest(string_to_array(unnest(string_to_array(event_labels, '&')), '=')) from table;
```

Now what I need is a way to actually perform an interval calculation (so 2018-04-04+11 days::interval), and I can if I only get a numbers list, but I need to also bind that result to each string.  So the goal is an output like this:

```
eventdate   |   event_label
2018-04-12  |   TTR
2018-04-20  |   DNV
```

Where eventdate is the schedule start + which day of the schedule the event is on.  I'm not sure how to take the unpacked string I created and use it to perform date calculations, and tie it to the string.

I've considered doing only one unnest, so that it's 11=TTR and 14=DNV, but I'm not sure how to take that to my desired result either.  Is there a way to read a string until you reach a certain character, and then use that in calculations, and then read every character past a certain character in a string into a new column?

I'm aware completely rewriting how this is handled would be ideal, but I did not initially write it, and I don't have the time or means to rewrite the ~20 locations this is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your table (I added `userid` column):

```
CREATE TABLE test(userid INTEGER, schedulestart DATE, event_labels VARCHAR);
```

And input data:

```
INSERT INTO test(userid,schedulestart , event_labels) VALUES 
(2,DATE '2018-04-04', '9=TTR&11=DNV&14=SWW&26=DNV&2=QQQ&43=FTW');
```

And finally the solution:

```
SELECT  
    userid,
    (schedulestart + (SPLIT_PART(kv,'=',1)||' days')::INTERVAL)::DATE AS eventdate,
    SPLIT_PART(kv,'=',2) AS event_label
FROM (
      SELECT 
         userid,schedulestart,
         REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(event_labels, '&') AS kv
      FROM test
      WHERE userid = 2
) a
```

Comment: Ooh, split_part is perfect.  Thank you!